# Cannot display data downloaded from Firestore using Listview.Builder and ListTile

Tags: flutter

I want to display a list from downloading the data from firestore.  The download is successful (the full list can be printed) but somehow it cannot be displayed.  Simply nothing is shown when I use the ListView.builder and ListTile.  Pls help what is the problem of my code.  Great thanks.

```
class DownloadDataScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  List<DocumentSnapshot> carparkList = []; //List for storing carparks

  _DownloadDataScreen createState() => _DownloadDataScreen();
}

class _DownloadDataScreen extends State<DownloadDataScreen> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readFromFirebase();
  }

  void readFromFirebase() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('carpark')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot cp) {
        widget.carparkList.add(cp);

        //to prove data are successfully downloaded
        print('printing cp');
        print(cp.data());
        print(cp.get('name'));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(
          'Car Park',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 9,
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.carparkList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(widget.carparkList[index].get('name')),
                      subtitle: Text(
                      widget.carparkList[index].get('district')),
                      onTap: () {
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the list in state add it to the top line of the initState method List carparkList = [];

```
class DownloadDataScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  _DownloadDataScreen createState() => _DownloadDataScreen();
}

class _DownloadDataScreen extends State<DownloadDataScreen> {

 List<DocumentSnapshot> carparkList = []; //List for storing carparks

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readFromFirebase();
  }

  void readFromFirebase() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('carpark')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((DocumentSnapshot cp) {
        widget.carparkList.add(cp);

        //to prove data are successfully downloaded
        print('printing cp');
        print(cp.data());
        print(cp.get('name'));
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your suggestion partially solves the problem.  The following error is displayed instead: RangeError(Index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty:0.    In addition, when I press Hot reload, the data can be properly shown.  It appears that the widget is built before the data is downloaded.  Any hint to further improve the code?

Comment: carparkList.length>0

return ListTile(
                      title: Text(widget.carparkList[index].get('name')),
                      subtitle: Text(
                      widget.carparkList[index].get('district')),
                      onTap: () {
                      },
                    );

range error is an error format given because there is no element in the list. If the length of the list is more than 0, it's fine if you say show it. You can wrap it with FutureBuilder for better control.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: It appears that your suggestion shows the correct direction. However, I am a complete newbie, so I am studying how to include the FutureBuilder into my code.  I will appreciate a lot if you could include the proposed code here.  Thank you very much

Comment: Finally, I figure out how to revise the code.  Thank you.